# How to get a fake test user logged in for pytest if my log in route reads information in from forms in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am using pytest to test my Flask application and the test for valid login fails because the fake user is not able to log in the way I'm doing it.

Once a user is logged in, server should redirect from Sign In page to Home page which contains some text and a flashed message. My test does not pass the asserts for the text/flashed messages on Home page. It passes assert for text that should be on Sign In page which means it's not successfully logging in and therefore not redirecting. I also printed the response data and it returns the html for Sign In page. It is not an issue with the app itself as on the server side everything is working fine. My valid_login_logout test in test_users.py and log in route in routes.py are below

```
def test_valid_login_logout(test_client, init_database):
    """
    #GIVEN a Flask application
    #WHEN the '/login' page is posted to (POST)
    #THEN check the response is valid
    """

    with test_client:
        response = test_client.post('/login',
                                data={'username':'AW', 'password':'FlaskWhat'},
                                follow_redirects=True)
        user = User.query.filter_by(username='AW').first()
        assert user.check_password('FlaskWhat')
        assert user in init_database.session
        assert response.status_code == 200
        #This is the point where it fails:
        print(response.data)
        assert b'Home' in response.data
        assert b'Click to Reset It' in response.data
        assert b'You were logged in' in response.data 
        assert b'Hello, AW!' in response.data
        assert b"Here are available items on sale" in response.data
        assert b"Welcome" in response.data  

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
                flash("Invalid username or password.")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
            flash('You were logged in')
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
                next_page = url_for('index')
            return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

I want the response data to be the redirected Home page but instead the response data is the original Sign In page which means the fake user isn't successfully logging in

Comment: Is the username 'AW' in your test database? Good practise is to have an empty test database and insert a test user as part of the test you are executing.

Comment: @tvgriek Yes! I added the users in a separate file in this way:
`@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def init_database():
    # Create the database and the database table
    db.create_all()

    user2 = User(username='AW', name='An Wa', email='aw@outlook.com', venmo='aw')
    user2.set_password('FlaskWhat')
    db.session.add(user2)
    db.session.commit()

    yield db

    db.drop_all()`

Comment: hard to tell, try to debug and see which part goes wrong: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0